# Cannot give .focus() to an element of a dropdown menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

Here is a Boostrap navigation bar, containing a `dropdown` menu, containing itself an `<input>`.

[image]

When I click on the dropdown menu, it is succesfully displayed. The value of the `<input>` is successfully changed to `Bonjour` but this `<input>` doesn't get the focus. Why ?

http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmdg4f/1/

**How to give the focus to a input contained in a dropdown menu with `.focus()` ?**

---

Code :

```
<div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-static-top" role="navigation">
    <div class="container">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="dropdown"> <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" id="maa">Dropdown<span class="caret"></span></a>
                <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" style="min-width: 250px;">
                    <li>
                        <div style="padding:4px 20px;">Link:</div>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <div style="padding:4px 20px;">
                            <input class="form-control" id="ha" type="text" placeholder="blabla" />
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
{
    var maa = document.getElementById('maa');
    console.log(maa);
    maa.addEventListener('click', function () {
        console.log($('#ha'));
        $('#ha').val('Bonjour');
        $('#ha').focus();
    });
};
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmdg4f/5/)***

The element exists at the time of the click, so changing its value and logging it will properly show the current state of the element. However, it has not been displayed yet and as a result focusing it will not really have any effect. You could probably refactor some small snippet in the library to expose a hook that you could use to make your focus work. Or, you could make the observation that in the very next event handler the element will be visible and use a small timeout.

```
maa.addEventListener('click', function () {
    console.log($('#ha'));
    $('#ha').val('Bonjour');
    setTimeout(function(){$('#ha').focus();},10);//timeout here
});
```

Comment: thanks it works! But when we click on this menu, for example for selecting the <input> box, the dropdown menu disappears... Can we disable auto-disappearing of dropdown... And set disappearing only when we click outside of the dropdown

Comment: Sure, just make the click event return false for that input. `$('#ha').click(function(){return false;});` http://jsfiddle.net/rzsmdg4f/11/

Comment: Thanks @TravisJ. You can already see this in action here : http://bigpicture.bi/jjwpi6 !  :) The 'Generate new URL when saving' doesn't work yet...

Comment: Do you know how to remove the default Boostrap-like `highlight` of the `<input>`, when it has focus ?

Comment: #ha:focus{
    transition:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    border:default;
}

Answer (score 2):

the simplest solution i came in mind is to just delay the focus. the reason its not focusing is because the element is not yet visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/xab7Leoq/

```
setTimeout(function() {
  $('#ha').focus();
}, 100);
```

another solution is to find out when its getting visible, and then do it. it may be a better solution yet more complicated. :)

edit1: stopping propagation:

```
// Prevents the propagation
$('#ha').click(function(ev) {
  ev.stopPropagation();
});
```

like in http://jsfiddle.net/xab7Leoq/

Comment: thanks as well! Do you know why the dropdown disappears when we click on the input? Could we disable this, and make the dropdown disappear only when we click outside ?

Comment: you'll need to stop the propagation. i added this on my answer.

Comment: Was working on an answer to this also, but since you beat me to it... just wanted to add, I don't think the problem is because it isn't visible yet.  If you place an input outside of the menu (that is always visible) and try to set focus to it, it also doesn't work.  I think something about the drop-down menu is taking the focus on click (after the click event returns).  You could possibly watch for a focus event or mouse-up event instead, but I'd just go with the setTimeout, it works.

Comment: If you are going to add more input fields to that dropdown (or others) I would target $('.dropdown-menu input') instead of just the single input element. Just a thought.

Answer (score 2):

An example using callback function. Man avoid to use setTimeout() function, because the results are unpredictable.

http://jsfiddle.net/v62tdn9z/

```
var $maa=$('#maa'), $ha=$('#ha');

$maa.mousedown( function () {
    $ha.val('Bonjour');
    $maa.mousemove(function () { $ha.focus(); });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Figured I might as well post an answer, even if late... since this seems to work well and doesn't require setTimeout:  http://jsfiddle.net/cvLbfttL/

```
$("#maa").focus(function () {
    $('#ha').val('Bonjour');
    $('#ha').focus();
    return false;
});
$('#ha').click(function(){return false;});
```

The anchor "maa" gets the focus when clicked, and it happens after the click callback/event returns.  So you can do your code in the focus event instead.  I couldn't figure out how to tab to the anchor inside JSFiddle, but I assume the code would also run if you set the focus to the anchor using some other method, but that should be fine I think, maybe even nice.

Answer (score 0):

Having a tabindex on the element could be the solution.  This worked in my case.

Comment: Please include some code (ideally with a runnable "code snippet") for this answer to be useful.